# Unable to get merchant NPC

Tags: terraria

I'm unable to get the merchant NPC to spawn.

I already have the demolitionist and the nurse. There are a couple of spare NPC suitable rooms, and 50+ silver coins, but even after waiting many nights, still no sign of a merchant.

Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12):

It turns out that the merchant had spawned!

I had created a shelter somewhere else in the world, and he had chosen that as his home.

I had actually destroyed the table in that shelter in order to avoid anyone living there, but it had a workbench, and it turns out that that is enough for an NPC to call it a home.

So the lesson learnt is if an NPC is mysteriously absent, he might already be somewhere you're not looking!

Answer (score 3):

From [Terraria Wiki:](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Merchant)

> The Merchant is an NPC that only
>   appears when all players have a
>   combined total of at least 50 silver
>   coins. You also require a house with a
>   door, at least one light source, a
>   chair, and a table, like with all
>   NPCs.
>
> Once the requirements are met, the
>   Merchant will move into the player's
>   world and sell items.
>
> He sells a multitude of items,
>   including some things that cannot be
>   otherwise obtained. Be patient, it
>   takes some time for the merchant to
>   move in.

I draw your attention to the last line:

> Be patient, it
>   takes some time for the merchant to
>   move in.

It would that the Merchant simply takes awhile to spawn after you have met the requirements.

Comment: I've tried speeding up time by using the window minimizing trick, but still no merchant..

Comment: How many in-game days has it been?

Comment: Maybe about 10? I understand that you need to have the 50 silver coins in your inventory for the merchant to come, so I'm staying in a safe spot and speeding up time to avoid having to go adventuring with 50 silver on me.

Comment: I did a bit more searching and was unable to find anyone with a similar problem :/ Try building another house? It could just be a bug.

Comment: I'm starting to think I might just have to start a new world :(

Comment: The NPCs are picky to the point of being buggy. I just built more, slightly different houses until they show up.

Comment: I built a house that met the requirements for the merchant after I had 50 silver and he showed up within a minute. Maybe you just need to leave your house and come back?

Answer (score -1):

if you're playing single player create at least 3 characters: your main char and two dummy chars. Procedure is that all of those created accounts should have at least 50 silver coins. you don't have to play multiplayer just to attract the merchant. Make sure you have a chest and put all of those 50 silver coins that every each of your character accumulated. It works on my game so it will probably work on your account.